# How to make vuejs template out of html?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I separate the script template and the html. This template made the doc too large. What should I do to cache it?

```
<script id="search-game-result-tpl" type="text/html">
<li class="" data-id=''>
    ...
</li>
</script>
<script id="search-tag-result-tpl" type="text/html">
<li class="" data-id=''>
    ...
</li>
</script>
<script id="search-question-result-tpl" type="text/html">
<li class="" data-id=''>
    ...
</li>
</script>
```

Comment: are you using vuejs?

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it. Don't post it into the question.

Comment: @deceze I do not have the permission.

Comment: @itbdw: you should do. Is there a blue button called "Answer Your Question" below?

Comment: @halfer after i submit, it says, "We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Comment: Aha, you've hit into the automatic answers ban - I thought you just could not see the button, it's easy to miss. [Read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/472495) to see how to unblock it.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author)*.

1, create a new template file, say "/js/template/tipwindow.html"

```
 <div class="container"
      ...
 </div>
```

2, in the main html file, use xmlhttlrequest to fetch the template and insert into main html and do the logic.

```
(function() {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/js/template/tipwindow.html', true);
        xhr.responseType = 'document';
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            var doc = e.target.response;
            var container = doc.querySelector('.container');
            document.body.appendChild(container);

            doLogic();
        }
        xhr.send();

        function doLogic() {
              .....
        }

}
```